# GoLang Implement an anonymous function of a custom type

Tags: go, anonymous-function

I have completed the `strains` exercise on exercism.io.  I am refactoring my solution.  For context: `Ints.Keep` takes in a predicate function and returns a filtered slice of type Ints for every element where the predicate function is true.  Conversely Discard returns all elements for which the predicate is not true.  Discard returns the inverse of Keep.  I implemented it like so:

```
func (i Ints) Keep(pred func(int) bool) (out Ints) {
    for _, elt := range i {
        if pred(elt) {
            out = append(out, elt)
        }
    }
    return
}

func (i Ints) Discard(f func(int) bool) Ints {
    return i.Keep(func(n int) bool { return !f(n) })
}
```

[Example usage](https://play.golang.org/p/3IjociPGV-x)

Now I am trying to clean it up slightly.  I want to create:

```
type Predicate func(int) bool
```

Then I want to implement Keep and Discard where the input is a `Predicate`.  I run into the issue when I try to create an anonymous function within Discard to return Keep:

```
func (i Ints) Discard(p Predicate) Ints {
    return i.Keep(Predicate(n int) { return !p(n) })
}
```

Is this possible?  I can't find a way to create an anonymous function of a named func type.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by casting the anonymous function as a `Predicate` Like this:

```
func (i Ints) Discard(p Predicate) Ints {
    return i.Keep(Predicate(func(i int) bool { return !p(i) }))
}
```

This isn't quite as clean as I wanted, but I bet this is the best.

Comment: You don't actually need to: https://play.golang.org/p/YdTfOorIc52. I'm missing something between strict readings of [**Type Identity**](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity) and [**Type definitions**](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions) that seems to apply to function types.

Comment: @muistooshort, [Assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability), second bullet. Function types aren't special. It works for struct types too, for instance, but doesn't really come up in practice: https://play.golang.org/p/fI_lZI3AMUA

Comment: @Peter Thanks, the "at least one of V or T is not a defined type" part in particular clarifies a few things.

Comment: @Peter i would strive to use the defined type everywhere https://play.golang.org/p/rKHc8V4qJ70, i guess that is more ordered way of working. You can use a type or the explicit defition, unluckely is not like PASCAL that enforces you use to use Type, as every type declaration is a type for the own.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are misunderstanding text replacement with type subtitution, see:

- `f func(int) bool` gets replaced by `p Predicate`
- `func` and `bool` (wrapping `(n int)`) somehow gets replaced by `Predicate`.

As far i remember type substitution is very straightforward and that is not the case here... "Mu is too short" highlights a good example if you insist on using type... although it is perfect to use anonymous functions definitions and declarations.

Another way to write code that comes to my mind that you might find useful is:

```
type Predicate func(int) bool

func (i Ints) Discard(pred Predicate) Ints {
    var anonymousComplementFunc Predicate = func(n int) bool {
        return !pred(n)
    }
    return i.Keep(anonymousComplementFunc)
}
```